# Laravel raw sql query returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a pretty complicated sql query which works fine when I test it in phpMyAdmin or similar.

I am trying to get it working in laravel now but I am so stuck. It just always returns empty array.

Here is what I have tried:

```
   $result = DB::select('SELECT sa.division, Sum(P) as games, Sum(W) as wins, 
Sum(D) as draws, Sum(L) as losses,SUM(F) as goals, SUM(A) as conceded, SUM(Pts) as  points FROM(SELECT gameday, division, home club, season, id, changes, penalties, ft, 1 P,
    IF (changes=2 OR penalties=2 OR (homegoals < awaygoals AND changes!=1 AND penalties!=1),1,0) W,
    IF (homegoals = awaygoals AND changes!=1 AND club!=2 AND penalties!=1 AND penalties!=2,1,0) D,
    IF (changes=1 OR penalties=1 OR homegoals > awaygoals,1,0) L,
    CASE WHEN changes=2 THEN 3 WHEN changes=1 THEN 0 ELSE awaygoals END F,
    CASE WHEN changes=2 THEN 0 WHEN changes=1 THEN 3 ELSE homegoals END A,
    CASE WHEN changes=2 OR penalties=2 OR (homegoals < awaygoals AND changes!=1) THEN 3 WHEN homegoals = awaygoals AND changes!=1 AND changes!=2 AND penalties!=1 AND penalties!=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
    FROM games) as tot, clubs s, series sa WHERE tot.club=s.id AND tot.division = sa.id AND s.url="awayteam" AND tot.ft=1 GROUP BY tot.division ORDER BY tot.division
    ');
    dd($result);
```

This is exactly how [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#running-queries) tell to do this.

What am I doing wrong? I would use query builder but my query is too complicated for that.

My query:

```
SELECT sa.division, 
       Sum(p)   AS games, 
       Sum(w)   AS wins, 
       Sum(d)   AS draws, 
       Sum(l)   AS losses, 
       Sum(f)   AS goals, 
       Sum(a)   AS conceded, 
       Sum(pts) AS points 
FROM  (SELECT gameday, 
              division, 
              home club, 
              season, 
              id, 
              changes, 
              penalties, 
              ft, 
              1                                     P, 
              IF (changes = 2 
                   OR penalties = 2 
                   OR ( homegoals < awaygoals 
                        AND changes != 1 
                        AND penalties != 1 ), 1, 0) W, 
              IF (homegoals = awaygoals 
                  AND changes != 1 
                  AND club != 2 
                  AND penalties != 1 
                  AND penalties != 2, 1, 0)         D, 
              IF (changes = 1 
                   OR penalties = 1 
                   OR homegoals > awaygoals, 1, 0)  L, 
              CASE 
                WHEN changes = 2 THEN 3 
                WHEN changes = 1 THEN 0 
                ELSE awaygoals 
              end                                   F, 
              CASE 
                WHEN changes = 2 THEN 0 
                WHEN changes = 1 THEN 3 
                ELSE homegoals 
              end                                   A, 
              CASE 
                WHEN changes = 2 
                      OR penalties = 2 
                      OR ( homegoals < awaygoals 
                           AND changes != 1 ) THEN 3 
                WHEN homegoals = awaygoals 
                     AND changes != 1 
                     AND changes != 2 
                     AND penalties != 1 
                     AND penalties != 2 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
              end                                   PTS 
       FROM   games) AS tot, 
      clubs s, 
      series sa 
WHERE  tot.club = s.id 
       AND tot.division = sa.id 
       AND s.url = "awayteam" 
       AND tot.ft = 1 
GROUP  BY tot.division 
ORDER  BY tot.division
```

Comment: Can you edit your query into your question? Is it possible that you stuck the semicolon onto your query? You usually exclude the semicolon in PHP and include it when you enter it into mysql (terminal).

Comment: Given that it's unlikely that `DB::select` is completely broken, maybe you could share your "complicated query" exact value as that's almost certainly where the trouble lies?

Comment: @Verba What's `home club`? It's your third selection column, I don't think it's valid to have spaces in columns. (Unless you wrap it with grave ticks)

Comment: Club is just an alias to home. Same "home as club". And the result isn't different if I take that off.

Comment: Why are you doing DB::select('select ****') try DB::raw('select ***')

Comment: @KhanShahrukh Because Laravel docs say so. If I change to DB::raw then result of dump is my actual sql query. Not the results of query.

Comment: You're certain this exact query works in SQL? If I make a simple table with a column named `home club` and do `SELECT home club FROM test` like you're doing it fails miserably on my MySQL install. Same for your column apparently named `1 <38 spaces> P`.

Comment: I am 100% sure. The is no column named "home club" in my table. Just "home". Club is just an alias to home (kinda useless alias though). And btw this query works fine when using Codeigniter. Not just on phpmyadmin or similar.